# Opencv array of Point issues

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a project based on Template Matching using Opencv.

I am trying to define an array of point which I am getting from the OpenCV function
`minMaxLoc()`, but I am getting these errors:

```
temp.cpp:45:35: error: ‘minval’ was not declared in this scope
temp.cpp:45:44: error: ‘maxval’ was not declared in this scope
temp.cpp:45:53: error: ‘minloc’ was not declared in this scope
temp.cpp:45:62: error: ‘maxloc’ was not declared in this scope
temp.cpp:56:69: error: request for member ‘cols’ in ‘ref_temp’, which is of non-class   type ‘cv::Mat [7]’
temp.cpp:56:93: error: request for member ‘rows’ in ‘ref_temp’, which is of non-class type ‘cv::Mat [7]’
make: *** [temp.o] Error 1
```

Here is what I have written:

```
Point minloc_array[7],maxloc_array[7];
double minval, maxval;
Point minloc, maxloc; 
int temp_count; for(temp_count=0;temp_count<8;temp_count++)
{

    cv::matchTemplate(ref_image, ref_temp[temp_count], des1, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
    cv::minMaxLoc(des1, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);
    while (true){
        double minval, maxval;
        Point minloc, maxloc;    
                if (maxval >= 0.9){
                    minloc_array[temp_count]= minloc;
                    maxloc_array[temp_count]= maxloc;
                    std::cout <<  "Template Matched " << std::endl ;
                    cv::rectangle(image,maxloc,cv::Point(maxloc.x +   ref_temp[temp_count].cols, maxloc.y+ref_temp[temp_count].rows),CV_RGB(0,255,0),2,8);
                    break;                  
                    }
                else
                    std::cout <<  "Template NOT Matched" << std::endl ;
                    break;
            }   




}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a number of issues.

- the length of minloc_array and maxloc_array does not agree with the limits of the for loop.
- the values of minval etc found by cv::minMaxLoc() will be hidden by the declarations
- you have perhaps not posted all relevant code, but it seems that ref_temp is not an array of cv::Mat
- the line numbers of the error messages are inconsistent with the code you posted, so presumably the latter is inaccurate, and it is impossible to say what the problem really is (do lines 42, 43 below really exist in

Here is your code with my annotations in comments:

```
41: Point minloc_array[7],maxloc_array[7];  // *** arrays have length 7 (max index is 6)
42: double minval, maxval;
43: Point minloc, maxloc; 
44: int temp_count;   // *** newline added for readability
44: for(temp_count = 0; temp_count < 8; temp_count++)
    // *** should be: temp_count < 7
45: {
46:    // *** error message is on this line  - is posted code accurate?
47:    cv::matchTemplate(ref_image, ref_temp[temp_count], des1, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
48:    cv::minMaxLoc(des1, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);
49:    while (true){
50:        double minval, maxval;   // *** hides minval, maxval in outer scope
51:        Point minloc, maxloc;    // ***  likewise
52:        if (maxval >= 0.9){
53:            minloc_array[temp_count]= minloc;
54:            maxloc_array[temp_count]= maxloc;
55:            std::cout <<  "Template Matched " << std::endl ;
56:            cv::rectangle(image,maxloc,cv::Point(maxloc.x +   ref_temp[temp_count].cols, maxloc.y+ref_temp[temp_count].rows),CV_RGB(0,255,0),2,8);
            // *** is ref_temp an array of Cv::Mat??
            break;                  
            }
        else
            std::cout <<  "Template NOT Matched" << std::endl ;
            break;
        }
```

}